# Setting column value based on comparison of two other columns in df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set the values in a column of a df to either 0 or 1 based on the comparison of two other columns.

My initial df would be this:

```
col1   col2    col3
1      3       NaN
5      1       NaN
7      4       NaN
5      10      NaN
```

I'm using this code to try to set values in `col3` to 1 where `col1` is greater than `col2` all other rows would be 0:

```
df[df['col1'] >= df['col2']]['col3'] = 1
df[df['col1'] < df['col2']]['col3'] = 0
```

This is for sure the wrong way to do it, but I'm not sure how else to approach it.

The desired result is a df with the following values:

```
col1   col2    col3
1      3       0
5      1       1
7      4       1
5      10      0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: `(df['col1']>=df['col2']).astype(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
df['col3'] = df.col1.ge(df.col2).view('i1')

print(df)

    col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     0
1     5     1     1
2     7     4     1
3     5    10     0
```

Comment: TIL `pandas.Series` has a `view` method (-:  This is on the order of 60% faster than `astype(int)`